# rosversion ros returns <unversioned>

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, rosversion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I just installed ROS Fuerte using the debian pkgs (desktop-full install) on a Ubuntu Precise (64 bit).
I tried to install some packages that check the version of ROS installed.
(using `roslib.stacks.get_stack_version('ros')`)
But `rosversion ros` returns `<unversioned>` and not 1.8.7, which is present in the /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/stack.yaml file. `rosversion -d` returns `fuerte` correctly.
My ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is set correctly.

Any idea how to fix the problem or what is causing this?

Thank you all!
Nick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37207/rosversion-ros-returns-%3Cunversioned%3E/) by [NickVT](https://answers.ros.org/users/2706/nickvt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in the current fuerte debian packages. It's been "fixed" but hasn't rolled out yet for some reason.

See this ticket: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3987

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6